# C#: Generics -- Infer the Generic Type of a Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics

I don't even know how to ask this question so I'll just give the code example.

Here is the domain:

```
public interface ISubscriptionProvider<T>
{
    void Subscribe(Action<T> callback);
}

public class Notification {}

public class CurrentUserNotifications : ISubscriptionProvider<Notification>
{
    public void Subscribe(Action<Notification> callback) { }
}
```

Here is the method I want to make magical:

```
public void Subscribe<P, T>(Action<T> callback) where P : ISubscriptionProvider<T>
{
    // body left out -- code uses P
}
```

This works, and here is how you call it:

```
Subscribe<CurrentUserNotifications, Notification>((n) => Console.WriteLine(n));
```

So the question is: **Is there any way to make it callable like this**:

```
Subscribe<CurrentUserNotifications>((n) => Console.WriteLine(n));
```

Basically, can it infer that the action type should be just from the `ISubscriptionProvider<T>`.

This subscribe method lives on a static class (its a static method, I left that part out).  The idea is that it will take care of constructing the `ISubscriptionProvider<T>` and keeping it a singleton (probably with structuremap).  So in use:

```
Messages.Subscribe<CurrentUserNotifications>((n) => Console.WriteLine(n));
```

Thanks!

Update:

This is kinda off topic, but if any scala people read this ...

... is be an example of a higher kinded type?  Something like:

```
public void Subscribe<P<T>>(Action<T> callback) { }
```

Where `P<_>` is the higher kinded type?

Comment: C# either infers all type parameters, or none.

Comment: clarified question -- not it is not, its on a static class.

Comment: In which class would the Subscribe<P,T> method be defined?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I was aware of that, but I wasn't sure if it could inspect the ISubscriptionProvider and infer from the generic type it has.  Technically all the information is there in that single type (CurrentUserNotifications) but I am not sure if c# can be made to use that.

Comment: @CodeInChaos its becoming clear the answer is no :)  Can you make this an answer so I can give you glorious, glorious karma?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use

```
public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> callback)
{
}
```

The type P Parameter is irrelevant in your scenario as it is never used.

Comment: sorry, I left out the body to avoid clutter but it does make use of P -- updated question.